# Assistance Splitting Column Data into Multiple Columns from Import-CSV

Tags: powershell

I import a CSV using import-csv command:

```
$P = Import-Csv "C:\MyCSV.csv"
```

I then run 'Get-Member':

```
$P | Get-Member
```

Output:

```
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Message     NoteProperty string Message=ABC 1234 DEFGH 123:3212 IJKLM         NOPQRST 23\13\19 ABC1234 0978AJD
```

I then run 'Format-Table':

```
$P | Format-Table
```

Output:

```
Message
-------
ABC 1234 DEFGH 123:3222 IJKNM NOPQRHT 23\13\19 ABC1234 0978AJD...
BAC 3214 DEFAH 123:3422 IJFLM NOPQRAT 23\13\18 ABC1234 0978AJD...
CEC 1534 DEFIH 123:3312 IJALM NOPQRFT 23\13\17 ABC1234 0978AJD...
3BC 1144 DAFGH 123:3612 IJZLM NOPQRGT 23\13\16 ABC1234 0978AJD...
```

I want to split this output up further by delimiting by space. I do not care about properly naming each new column. I just want to be able to then select whatever column header certain text falls under and export that output to a new CSV.

Ideal output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  etc                                                                                                                                                                                       
------- ------- ------- -------                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ABC     1234    DEFGH   123:3222 etc
```

So I can then run a command such as:

```
select Column5,Column8
```

or a command like

```
select Column15,Column58
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what your input looks like?  I suspect you can use Import-CSV more efficiently but I can't tell with the info provided.

Comment: Are you confident that each row will have the same number of spaces (and thus, the same number of columns)?

Comment: Yes, these are actually Windows Security event logs with a set format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do the job:

```
# fake reading in a CSV file as text
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
Message
ABC 1234 DEFGH 123:3222 IJKNM NOPQRHT 23\13\19 ABC1234 0978AJD
BAC 3214 DEFAH 123:3422 IJFLM NOPQRAT 23\13\18 ABC1234 0978AJD
CEC 1534 DEFIH 123:3312 IJALM NOPQRFT 23\13\17 ABC1234 0978AJD
3BC 1144 DAFGH 123:3612 IJZLM NOPQRGT 23\13\16 ABC1234 0978AJD
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$ColCount = $InStuff[1].Split(' ').Count

$Collection = $InStuff |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header (1..$ColCount).ForEach({"Column_$_"})

$Collection |
    Select-Object -Property 'Column_3', 'Column_7'
```

Output:

```
Column_3 Column_7
-------- --------
DEFGH    23\13\19
DEFAH    23\13\18
DEFIH    23\13\17
DAFGH    23\13\16
```

What it does:

- reads the file in as a text file, not a CSV file
- gets a count on the # of columns
- skips the 1st line
- creates a CSV import

  - sets the delimiter to `<space>`
  - sets the header to the range of `1..$ColCount`
- filters for the desired columns

Comment: Improvement suggestion: pre-pend column for readability `(1..$ColCount|%{"Column$_"})`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - kool! i shall do that now ... [*grin*]

Comment: Only flaw that I see is that you assume each row has the same number of columns. If the OP isn't sure if each row will have the same number of columns you may need to do an initial `$ColCount = $InStuff|%{$_.Split(' ').Count}|Measure-Object -Max |% Maximum`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - do you think that is likely? i agree that the idea makes sense, but i don't want to over-complicate the code when the OP seems rather new to it all ...

Comment: Probably not likely, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - then i think i will leave that out for now. i'm rather uncertain how much depth the OP wants at this  point.

Comment: @dy625 - the `fake reading ...` refers to the use of a here-string to embed test data in a script in a way that _emulates_ reading the data from a file. so - instead of your `$P = Import-Csv "C:\MyCSV.csv"` - use `Get-Content` to read the file as a text file instead of as a CSV file. ///// however, your decision to redesign the code that creates your data file will be simpler. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  

I am struggling here. How do I get the 'Get-Content' into the array automatically?  


`$P = Get-Content "MyCSV.csv"`
`$InStuff = @'`
`$P`
`'@ -split [environment]::NewLine`

Comment: @dy625 - take a look at `Get-Help Get-Content`. [*grin*] ///// that cmdlet creates an array when you read a text file with it. simply assign the output of the cmdlet to a $Var like this ... `$Var = Get-Content -LiteralPath 'FullFileName.csv'`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I understand that - but the array is reading the `$P` like it's text. I am unable to 'escape' it so it reads it properly as a variable. How do I 'escape it'? Or, if I consider that itself as an array - I am unable to then split the text, what is the proper syntax? `$P = Get-Content -Path 'MyCSV.csv' -split [environment]::NewLine` does not work.

Comment: @dy625 - oh! [*grin*] the ENTIRE block that starts with the `@'` and ends with `NewLine` is to be replaced with a call to `Get-Content`. ///// that structure - all of it - is a `here-string` with a split on newlines ... it emulates the output of using `Get-Content` on a file without requiring one to actually write the file out & then read it back in again. it is done for embedding test data in the script.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Firstly, I want to thank you for how prompt your replies are. However, something seems to break without `-split [environment]::NewLine`. Can you simply provide me the exact syntax I'd use? Right now it appears to be breaking each line into multiple columns - but the data remains only in the first column.

Comment: @dy625 - you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// try `$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath <your file name here>' just above the `$ColCount =` line. that will override the the previous `$InStuff` call with your file data.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Lee, unfortunately it's the same result. This is my result, hopefully this will shed some light on the issue. Any thoughts?:

Column_1   : ABC 1234 DEFGH 123:3222 IJKNM NOPQRHT 23\13\19 ABC1234 0978AJD...
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   : 
Column_1   : BAC 3214 DEFAH 123:3422 IJFLM NOPQRAT 23\13\18 ABC1234 0978AJD...
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   : 
Column_1   : CEC 1534 DEFIH 123:3312 IJALM NOPQRFT 23\13\17 ABC1234 0978AJD...
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   : 
... etc

Comment: @dy625 - in your original post just after `Output:`, you show that each row consists of a <space> delimited string. your current sample seems to agree with that. ///// please go back to your original post and enter the 1st 3 lines of the input file - the COMPLETE lines - so that i can see what is breaking things.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Happy Holidays, please see below my 'answer' to this post - as I am too low of a reputation to edit my own original post. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Lee, I am currently unable to edit my own post because my reputation is too low -_-. As such, I will respond to the post with the information you're requesting:

For your further insight, here is my current code that's not working:

```
    $InStuff = Get-Content -Path 'MyCSV.csv'

    $ColCount = $InStuff[1].Split(' ').Count

    $Collection = $InStuff |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header         (1..$ColCount).ForEach({"Column_$_"})

$Collection
```

Output. As you can see, all columns except Column_1 are empty:

```
Column_1   : <134>Dec 13 13:50:23 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 
Thu Dec 13 13:50:23 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy625 N/A 
Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on 
an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy625 Account 
Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object 
Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   
Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write 
Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX- 
XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   
Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   : 
...
Column_1   : <134>Dec 13 13:50:18 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 
Thu Dec 13 13:50:18 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy626 N/A 
Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on 
an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy626 Account 
Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object 
Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   
Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write 
Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX- 
XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   
Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   : 
...
Column_1   : <134>Dec 13 13:50:14 10.137.118.22 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 
Thu Dec 13 13:50:14 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy627 N/A 
Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on 
an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy627 Account 
Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object 
Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   
Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write 
Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX- 
XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   
Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
Column_2   : 
Column_3   : 
Column_4   : 
Column_5   :
```

As I stated before, I think the issue is that I don't know how to re-implement the `'-split [environment]::NewLine'` command with the updated syntax. As you can, see it's missing. I think this is the cause of the issue.

When I input the raw text as you suggest, with the entire first 3 lines, your syntax works correctly, as expected.

```
$InStuff = @'
Message
<134>Dec 13 13:50:23 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:23 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy625 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy625 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
<134>Dec 13 13:50:18 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:18 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy626 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy626 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
<134>Dec 13 13:50:14 10.137.118.22 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:14 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy627 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy627 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

    $ColCount = $InStuff[1].Split(' ').Count

   $Collection = $InStuff |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header     
    (1..$ColCount).ForEach({"Column_$_"})

    $Collection |
        Select-Object -Property 'Column_3', 'Column_7'
```

Output:

```
$Collection |
    Select-Object -Property 'Column_3', 'Column_7'

Column_3 Column_7
-------- --------
13:50:23 Security
13:50:18 Security
13:50:14 Security
```

Again, I think the issue is just that I don't know how to implement the `'-split [environment]::NewLine'`command.

```
$InStuff = Get-Content -Path 'MyCSV.csv' -split [environment]::NewLine
```

Error:

```
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'split'.
```

Anyway, I hope this sheds some clarity on the issue.

Comment: that is because your input data is _not at all_ like the demo data you supplied. [*grin*] please post just the input data - preferably the 1st three lines to provide some variety - to do realistic testing with.

Comment: Lee_Dailey I think you've caught on to my mistake. You are right - the issue is with the data itself. After reviewing my input data, it appears some logs were slightly different than others, some were 'Control Access' logs while others were 'Write Property' logs. Sorry for leading you on this wild goose chase - I'm pretty sure this case can now be resolved!!